# How to detect when the Java heap is nearly full and prevent "OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap"?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory

There a quite a few questions in SO related to the "OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap" error, but reading over them, most seem to discuss how to increase the heap size or profiling the app and detecting memory leaks.

I'm working on a project, that invovles analyzing the cost of a branch and bound algorithm.  For input small input sizes, the potential number of solutions to search grows at O(n!).  At a certain input size, n, I've encountered the "OutOfMemoryError" because the parial solutions are kept in a priority queue until ready to be treated, and the huge number of partial solutions in the queue fills up the memory.  So, I know I don't have a memory leak, and I don't necessarily want to increase the heap size.

What I'd like to do is simply detect when the memory is nearly full, then give the user a message that tells them what's going on and why the program is exiting (it's not necessary the program keep functioning at this point).  Is there a way to do this?  I have looked at the `java.lang.management` package, but it doesn't make much sense to me, and I've had difficulty finding decent example code.  Any explanation or example code is appreciated.

Comment: I suppose *not taking up all the memory* would be too easy and make too much sense...

Comment: "Not taking up all the memory would be too easy"...plese elaborate. Throwing more memory at it doesn't work...for O(n!) I might be able to treat a few more cases, but quickly the memory will fill up again.  Please explain your comment.

Comment: I would suggest you chunk and split your work and execute only the amount of chunks that you can handle. IF you need to save your partial results try a file or a database

Comment: @user1089416: I believe the generally accepted solution for resource problems with an O(!n) algorithm is to find an algorithm (or, failing that, a heuristic) with a better complexity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What I'd like to do is simply detect when the memory is nearly full, then give the user a message that tells them what's going on and why the program is exiting (it's not necessary the program keep functioning at this point).

That's difficult. Mostly because free memory is not really known before a garbage collection takes place, and a serious garbage collection usually only happens just before you run out.

What you can do is explain why the program has crashed *after the fact*:  Eclipse does this for example. You can catch the OutOfMemoryError just like any other Throwable, and show your message:

```
 try{
      heavyLifting();
 }
 catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
    showAMessage();   
 }
```

Comment: That is useful, thanks.  One follow-up, how often should "heavylifting()" be called? I know, bad question, as it depends on my program, but is it advisable to call that in method frequently?

Comment: `heavyLifting()` is your algorithm. My suggestion was to wrap your whole program into this try/catch block.

Comment: Duh! Sorry, I was in a hurry this morning. I gave this a try and it seems to work the way I want. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: It does not always work. Sometimes it is not enough memory to make the processing unit `catch`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the memory status using the `Runtime` api;

```
        // Memory status
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        long totalMemory = runtime.totalMemory();
        long freeMemory = runtime.freeMemory();

        boolean memoryOK = minFree <= freeMemory;
```

Comment: I don't think that will work correctly, because freeMemory() only measures memory that is already freed, not memory used by objects eligible for garbage collection. You'd have to call System.gc() right before, and even then it would not be completely dependable.

Comment: @Michael, agreed that knowing the current memory status does not give guarantees and garbagage collection plays a big role. The OP did ask how to gauge the memory status however. I think answering the question followed by advice on how to proceed after that isn't such a bad thing to do :-)

Comment: Thanks for the information...it may come in handy, but for now, Thilo's solution works, and keeps things simple.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple and direct solution is to catch the `OutOfMemoryError` at a very high level of the application and then just show the message, then close the application.

In theory, this could fail as there might not be enough memory to show the message, but in practice this will almost never happen because a lot of objects go out of scope when the error is caught, giving you almost certainly enough for simple tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the useful feedback. Also, your comment under my original question was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do much a part from making your code memory efficient. Even if you get to know that memory is about to full, and now `out of memory error` is about to come, there is very less that you can do, At best, you can request garbage collector to become active, but its a request. And rest assure, JVM will do its best to prevent out of memory error, If it still comes, most probably it was unavoidable with given code.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/mxbeans.html and more specifically the section related to memory "threshold".